# getLastLocation using Reflection with GoogleApiClient and LocationServices

Tags: java, android, reflection, google-play-services

I'm working on an Android Library and I need to remove the play services dependencies to be added by the developer who used my library. I need user location last location so I need to use reflection because the location library will not be included directly in my library.

But how to create the googleApiClient from the builder via reflection ?

Comment: hmmm, gradle? then use `provided` insted `compile` in `dependencies`

Comment: @Selvin `Warning:Project androidsdk: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:aar:7.5.0 is an Android Library.`

Comment: damn,  I forgot that it is aar.

Comment: apparently @Selvin android gradle plugin 1.3 which is in beta could work

Comment: yes, that's why i'm using the aar format.

Comment: anyway ... where is the problem in using reflection? it should be easy (but still pain in the a**) ... You wana help with translation some particular part of "normal" code to "reflection" ?

Comment: @Selvin i'm currently working on it, I'm on the listener parts, as you sayed it's quiet long (first really full pratice of it). Will answer the full code one finished

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler, Proxy and stuff? ... have a fun :)

Comment: http://selvin.pl/LocationPicker.zip ... i used jar from `ANDROID_SDK\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs` in library project as `provided` and compile against m2 google play library in app project ... as long as you will not use resources from google play lib in your lib it should work ...

Answer (score 1):

Digging into reflection and Play Services produce the following script. It contain the code for getting AdvertisingId and the location.

[Gist also available](https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/4ae1574993e698c43b5e).

```
private void getLocation(Context context) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getLocation");

    if (context.getPackageManager().checkPermission(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, context.getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            context.getPackageManager().checkPermission(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, context.getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        try {
            Class<?> apiClientBuilderClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder");
            Class<?> connectionCallbackClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks");
            Class<?> connectionFailedCallbackClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener");
            Class<?> locationServicesClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices");

            Constructor<?> constructorApiBuilder = apiClientBuilderClass.getConstructor(Context.class);
            Object objectApiBuilder = constructorApiBuilder.newInstance(mContext);

            // Create intance of listener ConnectionCallbacks
            Class<?>[] connectionClassArray = new Class<?>[1];
            connectionClassArray[0] = connectionCallbackClass;
            sGoogleApiClientListener = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    connectionCallbackClass.getClassLoader(), connectionClassArray, new GoogleApiClientListener());

            Method connectionMethodObject = apiClientBuilderClass.getMethod("addConnectionCallbacks", connectionCallbackClass);
            connectionMethodObject.invoke(objectApiBuilder, sGoogleApiClientListener);

            // Create instance of OnConnectionFailedListener listener

            Class<?>[] connectionFailedClassArray = new Class<?>[1];
            connectionFailedClassArray[0] = connectionFailedCallbackClass;
            sGoogleApiClientFailedListener = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    connectionFailedCallbackClass.getClassLoader(), connectionFailedClassArray, new GoogleApiClientFailedListener());

            Method connectionFailedMethodObject = apiClientBuilderClass.getMethod("addOnConnectionFailedListener", connectionFailedCallbackClass);
            connectionFailedMethodObject.invoke(objectApiBuilder, sGoogleApiClientFailedListener);

            // Add Api
            Method addApiMethod = apiClientBuilderClass.getMethod("addApi", Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api"));
            addApiMethod.invoke(objectApiBuilder, locationServicesClass.getField("API").get(null));

            // Build
            Method buildMethod = apiClientBuilderClass.getMethod("build");
            sGoogleApiClient = buildMethod.invoke(objectApiBuilder);

            // Connect
            for (Method method : sGoogleApiClient.getClass().getMethods()) {
                if (!"connect".equals(method.getName())) {
                    continue;
                }

                method.invoke(sGoogleApiClient);
                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Location is not essential, so it's not an error
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Exception on getLocation " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }

    } else {
        sLocation = "";
    }
}

// GoogleApiClient for Locationsucceded
public void onConnected() {
    Location lastLocation = null;
    try {
        // FusedLocationApi is a field of LocationServices, getting it.
        Class<?> locationServicesClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices");
        Class<?> locationProviderClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi");
        for (Method method : locationProviderClass.getMethods()) {
            if (!"getLastLocation".equals(method.getName())) {
                continue;
            }

            Object object = locationServicesClass.getField("FusedLocationApi").get(null);
            lastLocation = (Location) method.invoke(object, sGoogleApiClient);
            break;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Location is not essential, so it's not an error
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Exception on invoke onConnected for getLastLocation" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }

    // Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(sGoogleApiClient);

    if (lastLocation != null) {
        sLocation = lastLocation.getLatitude() + "," + lastLocation.getLongitude();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location received : " + sLocation);
    } else {
        sLocation = "";
    }

    newResourcesAvailable();
    unregisterConnectionCallbacks();
}

// GoogleApiClient for Location failed somewhere

public void onConnectionSuspended() {
    sLocation = "";

    newResourcesAvailable();
    unregisterConnectionCallbacks();
}

// GoogleApiClient for Location failed somewhere
public void onConnectionFailed() {
    sLocation = "";
    newResourcesAvailable();
    unregisterConnectionCallbacks();
}

private void unregisterConnectionCallbacks(){

    for (Method method : sGoogleApiClient.getClass().getMethods()) {
        if (!"unregisterConnectionCallbacks".equals(method.getName())) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            method.invoke(sGoogleApiClient, sGoogleApiClientListener);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // Exception always occur here but cannot make it work
        }
        break;
    }

    for (Method method : sGoogleApiClient.getClass().getMethods()) {
        if (!"unregisterConnectionFailedListener".equals(method.getName())) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            method.invoke(sGoogleApiClient, sGoogleApiClientFailedListener);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // Exception always occur here but cannot make it work
        }
        break;
    }
}

protected class RetrieveAdvertisingId extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String id = "";

        try {
            Object AdvertisingInfoObject = getAdvertisingInfoObject(mContext);
            id = (String) invokeInstanceMethod(AdvertisingInfoObject, "getId", null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Catch reflection exception and GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException |
            // GooglePlayServicesRepairableException

            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while getting AdvertisingId", e);
        }

        return id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String advertisingId) {
        super.onPostExecute(advertisingId);


        if (advertisingId != null && !advertisingId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Advertising ID retrieved: " + advertisingId);

            sAdvertisingId = advertisingId;
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "AdversitingId is not available");
            sAdvertisingId = "";
        }

        AsynchronousParameterManager.this.newResourcesAvailable();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the AdvertisingIdInfo object
 *
 * @param context the android context
 * @return the advertising id information object
 * @throws Exception
 */
private Object getAdvertisingInfoObject(Context context) throws Exception {
    return invokeStaticMethod(
            "com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient",
            "getAdvertisingIdInfo",
            new Class[]{Context.class},
            context
    );
}

/**
 * Invokes a static method within a class
 * if it can be found on the classpath.
 *
 * @param className  The full defined classname
 * @param methodName The name of the method to invoke
 * @param cArgs      The args that the method can take
 * @param args       The args to pass to the method on invocation
 * @return the result of the method invoke
 * @throws Exception
 */
private Object invokeStaticMethod(String className, String methodName,
                                  Class[] cArgs, Object... args) throws Exception {
    Class classObject = Class.forName(className);
    return invokeMethod(classObject, methodName, null, cArgs, args);
}

/**
 * Invokes a method on a static instance
 * within a class by reflection.
 *
 * @param instance   The instance to invoke a method on
 * @param methodName The name of the method to invoke
 * @param cArgs      The args that the method can take
 * @param args       The args to pass to the method on invocation
 * @return the result of the method invoke
 * @throws Exception
 */
private Object invokeInstanceMethod(Object instance, String methodName,
                                    Class[] cArgs, Object... args) throws Exception {
    Class classObject = instance.getClass();
    return invokeMethod(classObject, methodName, instance, cArgs, args);
}

/**
 * Invokes methods of a class via reflection
 *
 * @param classObject The class to attempt invocation on
 * @param methodName  The name of the method to invoke
 * @param instance    The object instance to invoke on
 * @param cArgs       The args that the method can take
 * @param args        The args to pass to the method on invocation
 * @return the result of the method invoke
 * @throws Exception
 */
private Object invokeMethod(Class classObject, String methodName, Object instance,
                            Class[] cArgs, Object... args) throws Exception {
    Method methodObject = classObject.getMethod(methodName, cArgs);
    return methodObject.invoke(instance, args);
}

private class GoogleApiClientListener implements InvocationHandler {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            if (args != null) {
                if (method.getName().equals("onConnected")) {
                    AsynchronousParameterManager.this.onConnected();
                } else if (method.getName().equals("onConnectionSuspended") ) {
                    AsynchronousParameterManager.this.onConnectionSuspended();
                }
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}


private class GoogleApiClientFailedListener implements InvocationHandler {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            if (method.getName().equals("onConnectionFailed")) {
                AsynchronousParameterManager.this.onConnectionFailed();
            }

            return 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about     `compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0') {
        transitive=true
    }`

Comment: @selvin this will only allow to Get user location from play services. It add dependencies to the location API and we Don't want that

Comment: then when you use the library you would add `exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"` it would be compiled without this dependencies

Comment: also you can use put all stuff that use gms to package like `pl.selvin.android.locationpicker.withgms` and exclude this package too (if you would not use it) and still using something from `pl.selvin.android.locationpicker`

Comment: But this will not solved the issue: I need to use Play Service but Play Services shouldn't be added the the final library @Selvin